# How Do I Get The Position of a field? (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the position of a value for a leaderboard...

my table currently looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is:

```
Sort table highest to lowest (xp) (where serverid = "")

Get the position of A user on it (id) 

and apply it to a value (e.g position = rows[0].positon) for use in node.js
```

**e.g?**

```
Positon | id | Serverid | xp
1        user1  server1  1221
3        user2  server1  32
2        user3  server1  321
4        user4  server1  19
```

but I have no clue on how to do it, if someone could give me a pointer in the direction I.E stuff I should look into that'd be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by serverid order by xp) as rnk
      from t
      where serverid = ?
     ) t
where id = ?;
```

Or, you can do this without window functions:

```
select count(*) + 1
from t
where t.serverid= ?
      t.xp > (select t.xp
              from t t2
              where t2.serverid = t.serverid and
                    t2.id = ?
             );
```